# Duplicate the executable for two different region of a microprocessor. srecord? cmake?

Tags: memory, cmake, embedded, elf, srecord

This is a question about performance, 
I am struggling with this for a while and my google-fu does not help me finding a way of fixing it.

I am crosscompiling an application for an embedded project. 
The microprocessor where the code resides has a memory splitted at half and I can decide to run the software from address_0 or addres_max/2.

at the moment i have a static library that is linked to main two times.

```
add_executable(mytarget_0 main.c)
target_link_libraries(mytarget_0 ${extralib})
set_target_properties(mytarget_0 PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_LOW} )
```

and an exact same that links to another region.

```
add_executable(mytarget_1 main.c)
target_link_libraries(mytarget_1 ${extralib})
set_target_properties(mytarget_1 PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MID} )
```

Basically the compilation of main is performed two times 
the linking is performed two times with different parameters.

I have this operation replicated for a lot of target and basically I would like to clean the code in order to improve compilation time.

My question now are 2:

- does someone have an idea about how to relocate the code without compiling it? I read about srecord but I am not sure I can use it for this purpose.
- does someone have an idea about how to change link flags in cmake without creating another target?

Comment: Relocating the code should be done in a linker script file (system-specific). S-record is one possible output format for the binary, you shouldn't make changes there. Suppose for example that the compiler places some data at "address of main + offset" and then that gets hardcoded in the machine code. If you would hack the s-record addresses, you would relocate the code physically, but it might still refer to the old addresses from inside the program.

Comment: Yes, I think it in the same way. Reading the srecord manual I was unsure if it could help getting different executables so I used a couple of line of my question to point out that I looked in that direction too. Thank you anyway for the clarification. It makes sense and cleared out some doubt.